# Date and Time Format In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Please Help! I need to get my date format in 6th August 2020 but what I have with the code below is 6-8-2020.

```js
// time and date
var today = new Date();

//var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var date = today.getDate() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getFullYear();

var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = dateTime;
```

```html
<div id='t1'></div>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    const MONTH = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    return date.getDate() +'th ' + MONTH[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
 }

let date = new Date();
console.log ( formatDate(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the moment library. You will need to install the package into your project but once you do you can do this with one line:

```
var today = moment().format("Do MMMM YYYY");
```

You can see how to install it here depending on the type of project you have: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Edit: you can also do the time as well in the same line:

```
var dateTime = moment().format("do MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you a closer result. I don't know where are you live in. However, this code is for the USA. If you wanna change it, just replace the country code.

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',  
})

console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jacob said, you could use some libraries like moment or date-fns.

Or go with something like this:

```js
// time and date
var today = new Date();

const month = today.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });

const ordinalDate = today.getDate() + ( [,'st','nd','rd'][/1?.$/.exec(today.getDate())] || 'th' );

var date = ordinalDate+'-'+month+'-'+today.getFullYear();

var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

var dateTime = date+' '+time;

console.log(dateTime);
```